# Stack snippets external library function reverses order

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

When adding external libraries to a stack snippet the `<script>` element is inserted before the already existing elements. So if you want to include a library which depends on another one you have to add the dependence last. This is contrary to the normal workflow.

Btw: Is is nescessary to include the script in the html area? Jsfiddle for example doesn't show them in the normal code windows, which is a cleaner approach in my opinion.

Comment: I had posted [a request @MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271776/2333214) for showing the external links in UI rather than `HTML` window, so did [this guy](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271648/external-resource-links-included-in-stack-snippets). I've also faced the *out-of-order-issue*.